# Git Repository Issue! Wrong Folder

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository

I need some help regarding my git repository. I'm creating a prototype website for my class with VS code and I realized that everything I have done so far has been under my user profile on my computer instead of under my "prototype" folder on my desktop. I haven't committed before and tried to do it just now and realized it was under my user profile. When I look at my “Changes”, it has a bunch of random untracked changes even my Stardew Valley saves (lol). This message has been popping up as well “The git repository at '/Users/myname’ has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.”

Is there a way I can change the git repository to a specific folder on my desktop (so I can commit) without losing all my progress on my website? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to prototype folder.

Clone your git repo (if not done so already).

Copy and paste your project to this folder.

Check git status to ensure only those changes appear.

Add, commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

If the only issue is that you want to have a git repo to that particular folder on the desktop, then I would copy all the relevant files to the "prototype" folder. Then start a new git repo there. Since you have made no commits before, it will just be clean and you can push all changes from then on like nothing happened.

Comment: Okay, thank you - I created a new git repo in the appropriate /Desktop/Prototype folder. Is there a way to delete the repo that is under /Users/"myname"? In VS code it is still tracking all the changes that happen there and there are 5000 of them.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Thanks for your help!